# AngularJS: Accessing current object in ng-show function for recursive directive

Tags: angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-show

Given the following code:

http://jsbin.com/EkIqAju/2/edit

How can I access the current object being evaluated in the `showQuestion()` function in the controller?

I need this to be able to validate which question to show based on the answer given in other questions. So I need to access the current evaluated object, check the constraints and then check the value of parent objects to evaluate if the question should be shown or not.

Comment: I was put off because of the size & complexity of your code. If you could take away some of the complexity (just for the purposes of solving this problem) you might find more people would take a look. Just a thought.